# Non alphanumeric characters replaced with a single space

Tags: php

Here's the thing I'm trying to get a search engine to pick up names entered as Doe J instead of Doe, J.

Here is my code:

```
$sql_where = array();

if (isset($_GET['name'])) {

    echo "Searched: {$_GET['name']}<br>";

    $names = explode(' ', trim(preg_replace('/ +/', ' ', $_GET['name'])));
    $names_cnt = count($names);

    if (2 == $names_cnt) {

        foreach ($names as $name_idx => $name) {

            if (($name_idx+1) == $names_cnt) {
                // last one
                $sql_where[] = "
                    (full_name like '% {$name}%')
                    ";
            } else {
                // first one
                $sql_where[] = "
                    (full_name like '{$name}%')
                    ";
            }
        }
    } else {

        $sql_where[] = "
            (full_name like '" . $DB->cleanString($_GET['name']) . "%')
            ";
```

I've tried `/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/` and a few other variations that have been unsuccessful.

Comment: you can use strpos() to see if there is a comma and replace it using str_replace()

Comment: "Unsuccessful" is not a built-in error message in any version of PHP.

Answer (score 2):

```
echo preg_replace( "`[^a-zA-Z0-9]+`", " ", $string); 
//replaces all non alpha numeric characters as " " 
//(and will not have duplicate spaces)
```

DEMO: http://codepad.org/7Ltx3kcr

Comment: This will have a problem with duplicate spaces.

Comment: @JasonMcCreary I fixed that :-)

Comment: My bad. Space is a non-alphanumeric character and therefore replaces itself. +1. Time to take a break…